# Bootstrap v3.3.7 : Cannot do the dropdown navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to make drop down navbar. I used bootstrap-3.3.7. I've following the tutorial from w3school. But I have a problem at my dropdown. When i clicked "About", it didn't appear list.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">


    <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" datatoggle="dropdown" href="#">About
                    <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contract</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is an incorrect implementation of Bootstrap. Read [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/navbars/) instead, do not trust W3Schools. (p.s. you should use the latest version, Bootstrap 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while checking your code i have found there is one syntax error, that is why you dropdown is not working in you  tag you are using datatoggle="dropdown" syntax and the correct syntax is data-toggle="dropdown" so use '-' sign between datatoggle and your problem is resolve.

Comment: You're right, my syntax datatoggle is incorrect. I've change into data-toggle, and its work. thank you